# Using UIManagedDocument to load a sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios5

I am using **UIManagedDocument's** Context to interact with my Core Data Model. However, I would like to initially load the Persistant Store contact from a local sqlite database that I have. I believe I am supposed to use **configurePersistentStoreCoordinatorForURL**: but have no idea how to do it. All I found on the Apple store was an example with App Delegate Core Data not this function or UIManagedDocument way. 
My source sqlite database in resource folder is called **source_from.sqlite** and the Data model is called  **Source.xcdatamodeld**

Also I prefer to have the new sqlite db in the document package. Not sure if the migration will happen automatically?

Thanks for your help,

Ross

Here is what I have and planning to do it in the initialize method:

```
-(void) initializeSourceDatabaseWithData:(UIManagedDocument *) sourceDatabase{
  // if no persistent store for the uidocument preload it 
  // from sqlite file
}

-(void) useDocument{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.sourceDatabase.fileURL path]]){
        [self.sourceDatabase saveToURL:self.sourceDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success){
            [self setupFetchedResultController]; 
            [self initializeSourceDatabaseWithData:self.sourceDatabase];

         }];
    }else if (self.sourceDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed){
        [self.sourceDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success){
         [self setupFetchedResultController];   
        }];
    }else if(self.sourceDatabase.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
        [self setupFetchedResultController];

    }
}

-(void) setSourceDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)sourceDatabase{
    if (sourceDatabase != _sourceDatabase){
        sourceDatabase = _sourceDatabase;
        [self useDocument];
    }
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!self.sourceDatabase){
        NSURL * url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Source Database"];
        self.sourceDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
    }
}
```

Comment: The following solution (http://readncode.com/blog/Load-SQLite-db-into-Core-Data-in-iOS-5/) Does what I need but using a utility seems like too much work for what I need. Is there anyway to just use the above function to set the persistent store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way is to subclass UIManagedDocument Class and implement the PersistanceStoreConfiguration so that it loads the file from outside the document package.